# Geocoder only working with chrome, not with firefox/IE/android

Tags: javascript, browser, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am trying to make landing page that redirects visitor to right language using geocoder to get countrycode and then redirecting to right language.
If I am in Finland it redirects me to www.mydomain.com/fi/index.html from www.mydomain.com/index.html

Those redirects are still in progress. I will fix those when geocoding is working on all browsers!

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>My test site</title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var geocoder;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction(){
    alert("Geocoder failed");
}

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



}

  function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
        if (results[1]) {
             for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "country") {
                    city= results[0].address_components[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        var countrycode = city.short_name.toLowerCase();

        if (countrycode == "gb") {
            countrycode = "en";
        }

        if (countrycode == "se" || countrycode == "ru") {
            window.location.replace("/" +countrycode+ "/index.html");
        }
        else if (countrycode == "fi") {
            window.location.replace("/fi/index.html");
        }
        else {
            window.location.replace("/en/index.html");
        }

        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()">
</body> 
</html>
```

This code works fine in google chrome but does nothing in firefox, IE or android.
Other browsers ask permission to use location but then nothing happens.

Can u help me to get this work on other browsers too?

Thank you!

Comment: "It doesn't work" is insufficient information. What doesn't work? E.g. is the text displayed in the wrong colour? Does it redirect to the wrong page? Please, explain.

Comment: I does nothing. Just ask permisson to use location and then nothing.
No error messages, no wrong redirects or anything..
When using chrome it ask permission and then redirects to right page.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works on Firefox only. It doesn't work on Chrome and IE. Perhaps you can change this code again to make it work on both Chrome and Firefox. I don't know if this can even work on IE. I'll look into that and update my code later.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>My test site</title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng);
}

function errorFunction(){
    alert("Geocoder failed");
}

var geocoder;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
  } 
}

function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
         for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {
                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "country") {
                    city= results[0].address_components[i];
                    break;
                }
             }
         }
      }
      var countrycode = city.short_name.toLowerCase();
      alert(countrycode);
    }
  });
}
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()">
</body> 
</html>
```